# SQL - Custom Select View after Joining Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, join, select, view, union

Very simple question and I just can't seem to figure it out.

I have the two tables below. I would like to write a select query that returns the following

```
| UID  | NAME    | DESCRIPTION | CC_CONFIG_UID |
├------+---------+-------------+---------------┤
| xxx  | HELLO_1 | NULL        | abc           |
| yyy  | WORLD_1 | NULL        | hij           |
| aaa  | NULL    | HELLO_2     | efg           |
| bbb  | NULL    | WORLD_2     | klm           |
```

**Table A:**

```
| UID  | NAME    | CC_CONFIG_UID |
|------+---------+---------------|
| xxx  | HELLO_1 | abc           |
| yyy  | WORLD_1 | hij           |
```

**Table B:**

```
| UID  | DESCRIPTION | CC_CONFIG_UID |
|------+-------------+---------------|
| aaa  | HELLO_2     | efg           |
| bbb  | WORLD_2     | klm           |
```

I have tried

```
(SELECT * FROM A) UNION (SELECT * FROM B)
```

But I get the following in return, which is close but not what I need:

```
| UID  | NAME    | CC_CONFIG_UID |  
├------+---------+---------------┤
| xxx  |HELLO_1  |  abc          |
| aaa  |HELLO_2  |  def          |
| yyy  |WORLD_1  |  hig          |
| bbb  |WORLD_2  |  klm          |
```

Comment: The text tables in your post help. Now: Please use words to explain how output is a function of input. Don't expect us to guess from an example. Eg you accepted an answer, but was there supposed to be sorting, or is order in your example an accident?--you don't say. Also give cut & paste & runnable code. Per [mcve]. (Best table formatting is tablular table initialization code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the columns.  Your tables have three columns, but you want the result set to have four:

```
select a.uid, a.name, null as description, a.cc_config_uid
from a
union all
select b.uid, null as name, bdescription, b.cc_config_uid
from b;
```

Comment: you are a life saver. That is EXACTLY what I need. Thank you